# Linearly Dependent Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

[image: Question]

I was wondering how to complete these questions. I have tried with $c=-2$, but I do not understand how to complete this.

Comment: Start by applying the definition of linearly dependent. You do know the definition, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Just write:
$$c\cdot(-3)\cdot(-1)+1\cdot1\cdot c+2\cdot2\cdot0-1\cdot(-3)\cdot2-c\cdot c\cdot0-(-1)\cdot2\cdot1=0,$$ which gives $c=-2$.

Comment: Does that find the determinate?

Comment: @Zacarura Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

To make $S$ a linearly dependent set, if you put those columns into a matrix, the determinant is zero.

$$\alpha \begin{bmatrix} c \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} + \beta \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \gamma \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ c \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

From the third row, what can you say about $\alpha$ and $\gamma$?